# What does the dialogue in Midnight in the Garden of Good and Evil mean?

Tags: plot-explanation, dialogue, clint-eastwood

What does John Cusack's character mean when he says "Nicholas himself wouldn't have as much eggs as you" in the movie "Midnight in the Garden of Good and Evil"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe it's a reference to [Tsar Nicholas II and his Fabergé Eggs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faberg%C3%A9_egg).  But I do not have a definitive source for that.